# htaccess does not convert sitemap.php to sitemap.xml

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already wrote yesterday about a problem with .htaccess that I solved thanks to the help of the user @RavinderSingh13. Now another small problem has arisen. I made sitemap.php which takes care of creating a sitemap by retrieving files from mysql database. Now I need to convert sitemap.php to sitemap.xml. But the .htaccess file does not allow me to find the requested file.
currently my .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine ON

##Excluding Indexes and MultiViews options here.
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex home.php

##Rule for adding / at end of urls.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

##Rules for non-existing pages to be served here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ core.php [QSA,L]
```

i added this, but unfortunately it doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

the sitemap.php file is located in the main root of the site. Could someone help me. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Add this sitemap rule just below `DirectoryIndex` line.

Comment: You want `sitemap.php to sitemap.xml` or `sitemap.xml to sitemap.php`?